# TextInputLayout display error on orientation change Android

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

Hi i am using TextInputLayout With TextInputEditText like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/userName_til"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etUserName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Style is

```
<style name="error_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Java Code is

```
tilUserName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.userName_til);
etUserName = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);

etUserName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Timber.d("OnTextChanged Called");
        if (s.length() < 1) {
            tilUserName.setErrorEnabled(true);
            tilUserName.setError(getString(R.string.please_enter_email_id));
        } else if (!AppUtils.isValidEmail(s)) {
            tilUserName.setErrorEnabled(true);
        tilUserName.setError(getString(R.string.please_enter_valid_email_id));
        } else {
            tilUserName.setError(null);
            tilUserName.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

I am using...

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

Reference Images portrait 
[image: While image in Normal time]

After landscape changed
[image: Landscape mode error displaying time]

On orientation changed automatically showing the error hint in EditText.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you setting the error text anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Are you sure `onTextChanged` never gets called, even before the orientation change?

Comment: @AbhishekJain Yes sure i kep't log also

Comment: Try putting simple `Log.d` instead of `Timber.d`.

Comment: @AbhishekJain  Ya it's calling OnTextChanged called on orientation change how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `TextWatcher` in a `Runnable` so that it gets attached after android has restored the state of your edittext. Something like this:

```
tilUserName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.userName_til);
etUserName = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
etUserName.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            etUserName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                Timber.d("OnTextChanged Called");
                if (s.length() < 1) {
                    tilUserName.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    tilUserName.setError(getString(R.string.please_enter_email_id));
                } else if (!AppUtils.isValidEmail(s)) {
                    tilUserName.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    tilUserName.setError(getString(R.string.please_enter_valid_email_id));
                } else {
                    tilUserName.setError(null);
                    tilUserName.setErrorEnabled(false);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
};
```

Referenced from [Android - onTextChanged() called on when phone orientation is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29449717/3857465).

Answer (score 0):

Because onTextChange() call when rotate screen (maybe :D)

You should check valid when user click done.

Comment: onTextChange() not triggered i checked kep't log check above and i disabled user click ?